# What does a radical mean here?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, applied-chemistry, radicals

I'm really confused as none of the definitions of radical on the internet compare to this.

This is from my college textbook of Applied Chemistry-

> Radicals
>
> Every inorganic compound is made up of two electrically charged parts
>   called *radicals*. One part has positive charge and is called basic
>   radical, while the other part has negative charge and is called acid
>   radical. Hence,
>
> ***An atom or a group of atoms which forms a part of an inorganic compound is called a radical.***
>
> **For example :**
>
> 1. Sodium Chloride is made up of two parts:
>
> **(i)** Sodium radical (Na<sup>+</sup>)  and   **(ii)** Chloride radical (Cl<sup>-</sup>)
>
> The two radicals combine to form sodium chloride molecule.
>
> 1. Copper sulphate is made up of two parts:
>
> **(i)** Cupric radical (Cu<sup>2+</sup>)  and   **(ii)** Sulphate radical (SO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>)
>
> The two radicals combine to form copper sulphate molecule.
>
> It should be noted that a radical cannot exist independently.

This definitely doesn't mean the same as free radicals. I don't think it means "functional group" because <strike>how can sodium be a functional group?!</strike>. Functional groups are in organic chemistry, right?

Can someone explain what the term "radical" means here?

Answer (score 4):

A radical, according to the IUPAC, has an unpaired electron. Radicals *may or may not* be ions.

> A molecular entity such as $\ce{.CH3}$, $\ce{.SnH3}$, $\ce{Cl.}$ possessing an unpaired electron.

http://goldbook.iupac.org/R05066.html

Contrary to your book's claim, the sodium ion is not considered a radical. It actually has all its electrons paired. It is isoelectronic with helium.

Regarding your book's usage of "radical:" your book's terminology is outdated. Here is the IUPAC statement on your book's usage of the term:

> In the past, the term 'radical' was used to designate a substituent
>   group bound to a molecular entity, as opposed to 'free radical', which
>   nowadays is simply called radical. **The bound entities may be called
>   groups or substituents, but should no longer be called radicals.**